# Need of template specifier to treat a type as a dependent template name in concept requires clause

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts

***Disclaimer:*** This question is out of pure curiosity, I do not intend to use such a construct (I can't even think of a relevant use-case for such a concept).

---

If we consider the following concept (to express the constraint of having a defined inner template type):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
concept has_template_type = requires(T)
{
    typename T::template type<U>;
};
```

I noticed that if I remove the `template` specifier in the `requires` clause (i.e. if I write `typename T::type<U>;` instead), [g++](/questions/tagged/g%2b%2b) still accepts the concept while [clang++](/questions/tagged/clang%2b%2b) rejects it with the following:

> ```
> <source>:4:18: error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'type' as a dependent template name
>    4 |     typename T::type<U>;
>      |                 ^
>      |                 template 
> 1 error generated.
> ```

<kbd>[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/344Wbesvr)</kbd>

Is GCC right/allowed to implicitly deduce that `type` is a dependent template name ?

While I'm suspecting Clang to be right, I would like to have confirmation and to know why.

Comment: I know the rules have changed recently and that `typename` is no longer required in certain circumstances but I do not recall the details. This is a link to the proposed change: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0634r3.html

Comment: @NathanOliver It's very interesting, I didn't know that. (Even if my question was about dropping `template` and not `typename` :D)

Comment: @NathanOliver clang claims support for this paper since version 16, not sure if this is it.

Comment: @NathanOliver The `typename` keyword here is used with a different meaning that the one you refer to. Here is is part of the [_type-requirement_](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.req.type) syntax in _requires-clauses_, not the `typename` in a [_typename-specifier_](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#nt:typename-specifier) used as a _type-specifier_. These two are unrelated. They could have been distinct keywords. The `typename` here is absolutely necessary in any case, because it introduces a requirement with a completely different meaning than without it.

Comment: The grammar for _type-requirement_ doesn't even permit a `template` in that position, see links in my previous comments. There can't be any ambiguity with `<`, because the _type-requirement_ can't be an expression. Not sure the rules on interpreting `<` do correctly consider that though.

Comment: @user17732522 considering http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.names#3.4 it seems that https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res.general#4 is missing a type-only context for the component names of a *type-requirement*.

Comment: @BrianBi That was my impression as well.

Comment: @BrianBi I opened a CWG issue request for this yesterday: https://github.com/cplusplus/CWG/issues/436